# Change Field Text

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I would like to change the text in a field based on the choice of the **same field**:

When text Green choice selected, it will be displayed as a big Green dot, so goes to amber and red.

Can it be done using JSON?

Comment: What are the choices/options for your choice field?

Answer (score 1):

Use below JSON code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=if(@currentField == '', '', '•')",
    "style": {
        "color": "=if(@currentField == 'Amber', '#FFBF00', @currentField)",
        "font-size": "5em"
    }
}
```

**Choice column settings**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

---

**Note**:

1. You can adjust the `font-size` & the color codes (Hex) as per your requirements.
2. Here I have added the choices same as the color name. So, I have used `@currentField` in `else` block of `if` condition in `color` property.

If you have different choices, you can change it like:

```
"color": "=if(@currentField == 'In Progress', '#FFBF00', if(@currentField == 'Not Started', 'red', if(@currentField == 'Completed', 'green', '')))",
```

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.